# Traceback Output with functions

Tags: python, output, traceback

As you can see by my code, I'm trying to create a program of a Carpet fitting service! But I'm not sure why it stops when it gets to the second function! Can you analyse my code and try to show me what is wrong? I fear that you will only understand my problem if you see the rest of the code. Keep in mind, I am a very new beginner.

Problem (in code - i cannot locate it):

```
https://pastebin.com/SWMYEAfE
```

Output:

```
This is Carpet Diem Carpets and we hope we are able to help you today!
We first need your personal details, so can you please choose your title.
Mr, Mrs, Miss, Ms, Dr, Lady or Lord?Lord
Well, what is your last name, Lord?
>>Test
Here at Carpet Diem Carpets...
We offer a variety of different levels of quality - 
With varying prices, of course, Lord Test!
We can fit your carpets at £6.50 per square meter - the Basic level.
Standard for £18.75.
And, for those who like to live as the very best, Luxury for £29.50!
There is also a 3.75 fee per square meter.
How many rooms do you want 'carpeted'?
>>3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikec\OneDrive - Ilford County High School\Computing HW.py", line 144, in <module>
    loopquality()
  File "C:\Users\mikec\OneDrive - Ilford County High School\Computing HW.py", line 28, in loopquality
    for x in range(nor):
TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
>>>
```

Comment: `for x in range(nor)` passes the function `nor` instead of the result of calling `nor()`, hence the error message.

Comment: Thanks, Peter! I didn't understand your message earlier, but just did. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two *major* errors that stand out to me immediately as I ran through your code:

- Variable [scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) issues.
- Attribute name overwriting issues.

You are calling `range` on `nor`. I can see that you meant to call it on the variable `nor` that is defined inside of the function `nor` and not the function itself.

There are two immediate solutions, either you create a variable called `nor_val` (or anything different from `nor`), in the scope above (where you defined all the other variables); and update that variable inside of your `nor` function and use it in the `range` call. The second option is to make your `nor` function return the `nor` attribute at the end of execution, and instead of calling `range(nor)` you would call `range(nor())`.

In the first case, you would add a line like `nor_val = 0` where you are declaring your attributes, and then replace all instances of `nor` where you mean the variable (not the function) with `nor_val`.

In the second case, you would add a line like `return nor` at the end of your `nor` function, and change the `range(nor)` to be `range(nor())`.

However, in both cases, your variable naming is not very intuitive. You should try to not reuse names as they could cause this type of confusion. Your `nor` function does not describe what the function actually does. I might call it something like `get_number_rooms` or something along those lines, and I would call the `nor` variable maybe `rooms`.

Comment: You know - you've helped a tremendous amount. I've decided to get rid of the function all together and cleared up my variable names, and it's worked like a charm!

Comment: Glad to help! Learning programming is all trial and error, don't be afraid to make mistakes: Google is your best friend.